# Django merging between two querysets by adding an element from one queryset to the other every nth element

Tags: django, django-templates

Assume I have in my model "movies" of several types:
E.g.: Action, Drama, Fantasy etc...

In my template I would like to list the 50 most recent movies (sorted by date). 
Which is rather straight forward E.g.:

```
Movies.order_by('-date')[0:50]
```

However, I have an additional requirement: I would like to list Action movies (sorted by date) every 3 movies of other types:

E.g.:

```
(0) Drama 12/3
(1) Adventure 11/3
(2) Science 10/3
**(3) Action 11/3**
(4) Sci-Fi 9/3
(5) Sci-Fi 8/3
(6) Adventure 4/3
**(7) Action 8/3**
(8) Drama
.
.
.
(50) ...
```

In other words, merge two query sets:

1. movies sorted by date of all movies excluding action movies.
2. movies sorted by date of only actions movies.

The new query set (or list?) should be 3 items from the first query set and 1 item from the other query set.

Comment: wouldn't **`moivies_except_action_qs[:3] | action_movies_qs[:1]`** do the job?

Comment: Wouldn't that apply to the first 4 results? (I need 50 in the list).

Answer (score 0):

Would be very helpful if someone can offer a better solution, but this is what I had done:

I converted the two query sets to lists.
And then used the [following example code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-selective-merge-list-every-nth-position/) to merge the lists based on my requirements.